SwiftUI ScrollViewReader scrollTo doesn't scroll all the way to top
I want the ScrollView to scroll to top when I tap on the tab. It works but it stops parallel to the navigation title and doesn't scroll all the way below the title as expected.
The current behaviour is,
1st tap on tab: scrolls parallel to the navigation title (Image 1)
Tap again: scrolls below nav title as expected (Image 2)
This is a poc of a much larger code so using a ListView is not an option.


struct Tabs {
    static let One = "1"
    static let Two = "2"
    static let Three = "3"
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var scrollToTop = false
  @State private var currentTab: String = Tabs.One
  var body: some View {
      TabView(selection: tabSelection) {
        TestView(scrollToTop: $scrollToTop)
          .tabItem {
            Label("First", systemImage: "1.circle")
          }.tag(Tabs.One)
      }
  }

  var tabSelection: Binding<String> {
    Binding( get: {
      currentTab
    }, set: { newValue in
      /// Tapped on the same tab.
      if newValue  == currentTab {
        switch newValue {
        case Tabs.One:
          scrollToTop = true
        case Tabs.Two:
          print(newValue)
        case Tabs.Three:
          print(newValue)
        default:
          return
        }
      }
      currentTab = newValue
    })
  }
}

struct TestView: View {
  @Binding var scrollToTop: Bool
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ScrollView {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
          LazyVStack {
            Text("Text 0")
              .id(0)
            

            // Simulating other views (these views will be added manually in the real app without the ForEach)
            ForEach(1...50, id: \.self) { index in
              Text("Text \(index)")
            }
          }
          .navigationTitle("Title")
          .onChange(of: scrollToTop) {
            if scrollToTop {
              withAnimation { // works without withAnimation only if scroll is not ongoing.
                proxy.scrollTo(0)
                // proxy.scrollTo(0, anchor: .bottom) doesn't work with any anchor as well
              }
              scrollToTop = false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

tried setting anchor of scrollTo, not working
tried without withAnimation. This works (although it's ugly) if scrolling is not ongoing. If you tap the tab while scroll is still happening the behaviour is even stranger.

The first text in the ForEach as an id of 0 which the same as the text outside the loop. That may be the cause of the problem. Use an id of -1 for the text outside the loop.

Good catch but this is a typo. I've corrected it. Fixing this doesn't change anything.

Your example code doesn't look like your screenshots, because there is no gap between Text 0 and Text 1. Without the gap, scrolling to the top also seems to work quite reliably. The gap may be causing the issue, because a  LazyVStack will estimate the height to be scrolled based on the content that is already being rendered. The problem can in fact be reproduced by adding .padding(.bottom, 20) to Text 0. See Content with variable height in a LazyVStack inside a ScrollView not scrolled properly to the bottom for a possible workaround.

@BenzyNeez Even without the gap it doesn't work. Scrolling stops right on top of the nav bar.

The id you wrote in Foreach and the id of Text("Text 0") have the same ids, so you can change one of these ids and fix it according to which one you want to be unique.
 Text("Text 0")
     .id(0)                          
     // Simulating other views (these views will be added manually in the real app without the ForEach)
    ForEach(0...50, id: \.self) { index in
    Text("Text \(index)")
     }


Good catch but this is a typo. I've corrected it. Fixing this doesn't change anything.
